# Proving $H$ is a subgroup of $GL(2,\Bbb{R})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G=GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and 
>   $$H=\Bigg\{{\begin{bmatrix} \cos{\theta} & \sin{\theta}\\ -\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{bmatrix}} : \theta \in \mathbb{R}\Bigg\}$$
>
> Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

So far I have that the identity element is:\begin{bmatrix} {1} & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} by multiplying H by \begin{bmatrix} \frac {\cos{2\theta}+1}{2\cos\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\ \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} \end{bmatrix}

but I'm unsure how to show $H \neq \emptyset$ and if $\alpha, \beta \in H$, then $\alpha \beta^{-1} \in H$. (which I'm assuming is the correct direction into proving $H$ is a subgroup of $G$)

Any advice/hints is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got the identity as $\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$.

Comment: The identity element can not depend on $\theta$. Look for a matrix $E$ such that for every $A\in G, AE=EA=A$.

Comment: To prove the subset $H$ being a subgroup of $G$, you want to show that the identity of $G$ is in $H$, so that $H$ is nonempty.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown sorry meant to write what I just edited.

Comment: @edm so all i need to prove is the identity of H is in G which will conclude that H is a subgroup of G?

Comment: No, of course not. It is not the case that any old subset containing the identity is a subgroup. But surely somewhere you have some notes telling you what needs to be done to prove something is a subgroup?

Comment: I've read so many different things from notes/online I think I'm just confusing myself - from my notes I have the following; to prove that H is a subgroup of G we must show that H is associative, has an identity, has an inverse for every element and is closed under the operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used matrices for a while in latex and apologize for any bad formatting. Hopefully someone kind enough can fix it. Also, I am assuming the operation defined on $G$, and thus $H$ is the usual multiplication of matrices.

Note that $H\subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$ $\iff$ for each pair $x,y\in H$, we have $xy^{-1}\in H$

Take $x,y\in H$

I.e. for $\theta_1$, $\theta_2\in \mathbb{R}$, $x$ and $y$ are of the form:

$$x=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_1) & \sin(\theta_1) \\
    -\sin(\theta_1) & \cos(\theta_1) \\
\end{bmatrix}
, \ y=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_2) & \sin(\theta_2) \\
    -\sin(\theta_2) & \cos(\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Noting $\det(y)=\cos^2(\theta_2)+\sin^2(\theta_2)=1$, we see
$$y^{-1}=\frac {1}{\det(y)}\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_2) & -\sin(\theta_2) \\
    \sin(\theta_2) & \cos(\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_2) & -\sin(\theta_2) \\
    \sin(\theta_2) & \cos(\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

So,

$$xy^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_1) & \sin(\theta_1) \\
    -\sin(\theta_1) & \cos(\theta_1) \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_2) & -\sin(\theta_2) \\
    \sin(\theta_2) & \cos(\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2) & -\cos(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)+\sin(\theta_1)cos(\theta_2) \\
    -\sin(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2) & \sin(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_2)+\cos(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix}
    \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) & \sin(\theta_1-\theta_2) \\
    -\sin(\theta_1-\theta_2) & \cos(\theta_1-\theta_2) \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here I used the angle sum formulas.

Clearly $xy^{-1}\in H$ since $\theta_1-\theta_2\in \mathbb{R}$

Thus $H\subset G$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: @Mark : use \sin for sine and \cos for cosine

Comment: @Reety: One can also say that $H$ is a subgroup of $SL(2, \Bbb{R})$

Comment: I was going to mention why $H$ is indeed a subset of $G$, which implies it's a subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, (since the determinant of any matrix in $H$ is $1$, but I guess you beat me to it!. Nice catch. (+1)

Comment: @ChinnapparajR I was just going to ask if it was, cool!